How to paste numbers in existing empy rows in variable using syntax in SPSS
I have a very very large data base with several observations coming from one participant (multiple participants, multiple lines per participant). I want to copy and paste a value in a column to fill in the missing values in the same column. See an exemple :



x
Variable 1




P1
45


P1
-


P1
-


P1
-


P2
53


P2
-


P3
27


P3
-


P3
-


P3
-


P3
-


P4
45


P5
56



What syntax can I use to tell SPSS to copy paste the value, for exemple for P1 "45", to the following empty values for this participant ?
I tried doing it by hand but my database is huge and I will lose hours if I do not find a way.

Here is one way to do this, assuming there is only one value per participant and that you want this value to be copied to all the rows of that participant:
aggregate /outfile=* mode=addvariables overwritevars=yes /break=x /Variable1=max(Variable1).


This can also be a solution. However, you have to rewrite it for every different x and Variable 1 value.
if (x="P1" and SYSMIS(Variable1)) Variable1=45.

If there is only one not-missing value for each participant than eli-k's answer is perfect.

If there are not other variables in this dataset that are different within each x or participant, i would consider deleting all of the rows containing a missing value for Variable 1. This will allow you to paste or append new rows on the bottom of the dataset.
You may be using the blank values to inform you how many responses you are expecting from a participant, but you could easily track the number of expected responses in a separate dataset (P1 = 4, P2 = 2, P3 = 5). Now you can aggregate your main file to obtain a count of responses to compare to this new dataset that is tracking expected responses.
DATASET DECLARE ResultsAgged.
AGGREGATE
/OUTFILE='ResultsAgged'
/BREAK=x
/CountOfResponses=N.

If there are additional identifying variables that you need (e.g. demographics for participants), you can always merge those in as needed for analysis from a separate database or file. Just maintain a running data file where you are always adding data and a separate file for demographics. When you run analysis, rely upon syntax to merge the two together temporarily for a combined dataset.
DATASET ACTIVATE Results.
MATCH FILES /FILE=*
/TABLE='Demographics'
/BY x.
EXECUTE.

This will provide a much more comfortable workflow that reduces the chances of losing good data and minimizing the size of your datasets.
